# Using OCMockito to mock methods that are void

Tags: ios, tdd, ocmockito, ochamcrest

In using OCMockito, the below works great:

```
DSAPIManager *mockAPIManager = mock([DSAPIManager class]);
[given([mockAPIManager initWithBaseURL:[mockAPIManager baseURL]]) willReturn:[DSAPIManager sharedAPIManager]];
```

However when I try the same thing on a method with multiple arguments (see code below), I get an "Argument type 'void' is incomplete' compiler error.

```
DSAPIManager *mockAPIManager = mock([DSAPIManager class]);
[given([mockAPIManager setLoginCredentialsWithEmail:@""
                                           password:@""]) willReturn:@""];
```

Does anyone know the right way to go about this?

Edit

My original intent in asking this question was to resolve an issue of getting a compiler error when I try the following:

```
[given([mockAPIManager setLoginCredentialsWithEmail:@"" password:@""]) willDo:^id(NSInvocation *invocation) {
        // Mock implementation goes here
}];
```

The method signature of the method I'm trying to mock is:

```
- (void)setLoginCredentialsWithEmail:(NSString *)email password:(NSString *)password;
```

What I'm actually trying to do is to mock out the implementation of a `void` method. (Given a `void` method, mock out the implementation of the method with a block. For my purposes the method returns a completion block, that takes in two arguments. I would like to construct those two arguments and then run the completion block inside of the mocked out implementation block.)

Comment: What is the line where you create `mockAPIManager`?

Comment: @JonReid added the line to the code above.

Comment: Thanks. What is the return type of the second method?

Comment: Sorry @JonReid I've realized I was asking the wrong question. I edited the above with my specific use case. The basic question is can I use OCMockito to mock out `void` methods that have some side effects. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCMockito doesn't yet support stubbing of void methods. That's because until `willThrow:` and `willDo:` came along, there was no need. It will be added as a feature soon. You can track progress in https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito/pull/93

Answer (score 3):

Now you can use givenVoid like this

```
[givenVoid([mockAPIManager setLoginCredentialsWithEmail:@"" password:@""]) willDo:^id(NSInvocation *invocation) {
        // Mock implementation goes here
}];
```